# Making a Caesar Cipher Function Encrypt With an Exclamation Mark

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

Can somebody please help me make a function that encrypts a message given that includes an exclamation mark in the message. eg: HOWDY! Hello. 
As of right now the output of my function for (HOWDY! Hello.) is

```
Your translated text is:
MTBIDEEMJQQTE
```

when it really should be :

```
Your translated text is:
MTBID! Mello.
```

My full code:

```
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
message = ""
encryptedmessage = " "
keynumber = 0

def encrypt():
 global message
 global encryptedmessage
 global keynumber
 print()
 print()
 message = str(input("Enter your message:"))
 print()
 print()
 keynumber = int(input("Enter the key number (1-26)"))
 print()
 print()
 for i in message:
  position = alphabet.find(i)
  newposition = (position+5)%26
  encryptedmessage +=alphabet[newposition]
 print("Your translated text is:")
 print(encryptedmessage)


def decrypt():
 global message
 global encryptedmessage
 global keynumber
 message = str(input("Enter your message:"))
 keynumber = int(input("Enter the key number (1-26)"))


action = input("Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message?")

if action == "encrypt":
 encrypt()
if action == "decrypt":
 decrypt()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alphabet.find(i)` will be `-1` if `i` isn't in `alphabet`. When this happens you should just copy `i` to the encrypted message instead of encoding it.

```
position = alphabet.find(i)
if position == -1:
    encryptedmessage += i
else:
    newPosition = (position + 5) % 26
    encryptedmessage += alphabet[newPosition]
```

Comment: How might I do that?

Comment: That's what I show in the answer: `encryptedmessage += i`

Comment: Oh thank you, the first part of (HOWDY!) works, but the second part (Hello.) does not the output is : (MTBID! MJQQT.) when the output should be (MTBID! Mello.)

Comment: @bangers123 Alphabet has 52 characters, but you're using `(position + 5) % 26`, so it converts everything to uppercase letters.

Comment: Is it possible to add this code to my decrypt function with minor changes?

Comment: Yes, you use the same `if` statement. If it returns `-1` you copy `i` to the decrypted message, otherwise you subtract 5.